# Windows 7 and Ghost

Tags: windows-7, windows, norton-ghost, imaging

I am in charge of prepping Win 7 for our environment and before I get started there are a few items I need some help with.  We have 90+ license keys but I do not want to use any to test with and the installation that we have auto activates.  Also I DO NOT have the option to change product key and I think it has to do with the image we have from Dell.

1.) I have seen somewhere on the net there are 30 day keys from Microsoft.  Am I just dreaming? - If not I believe I have a workaround - Create 2 bat files one named Start and the other Enter.  Start will call the enter bat file that does this

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
echo.
ECHO    This will propmt you for a new 
ECHO    product key.
ECHO    The key will need to be provided as such
ECHO    xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
echo.
set /p answer=What is the new prodcut key?
slmgr /ipk %answer%
```

Easy peasy right.

2.) We use Ghost Solution Suite and my boss wants to stick with that since they do not have any issues.  I read an article [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/c35ab71e-4534-4c12-bde6-63d9ae6c09cb) 3rd post down by Ang101.  Can anyone confirm this?  We are wanting this done within a month so hopefully I can get some solid answers.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows 7 without a key, and it puts it into a 30 day trial mode.

You can then later enter the key(s) directly into Windows via the "Change product key" link:

[image]

The intention is for testing and prepping systems. :)

Keyless install references: [1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/can-i-install-windows-7-without-initially/9bbaf0e5-479e-4991-a781-6897b736b601), [2](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120325143155AAkXQp6), [3](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/w7itproinstall/thread/7d72d093-eee7-40f4-9550-cbda71b2fcdd), [4](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/windows-7-installation-win7-ultimate-rtm.aspx)

[Picture source](http://www.sizzledcore.com/2009/10/26/how-to-change-windows-7-product-key/).

Comment: Ahh I forgot to mention that.  That option is not there :(  Techie thanks so much for your input.  I will change the original post.

Comment: That link is in every version of Win7 I've seen.  What version/edition are you using exactly?  Is this a manufacturer's OEM copy you are using as the source?

Comment: The fact that you can install with NO key is really the answer I'm trying to give.  You _can_ use slmgr to input the key afterwards if the link is missing, and you seem to have that part figured out already. ;)

Comment: Sweet, I guess when I create my autounattended.xml file (see part 2 of OP) then it should all work well and I can start knocking this out.

http://i45.tinypic.com/2gwdd3n.jpg - Just proof Im not crazy :)

Comment: Hopefully your Dell OEM disks aren't BIOS locked and actually let you specify The or No key during install. :/

Comment: Knowing dell it probably is lol.  I will attempt this in the next few days and hopefully by that time someone has address issue 2.